# Calculate sum of sum using Z transform

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, z-transform

$$S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{2^k}$$

We know that if one signal y can be written as $$y(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} x(k)$$
then it's Z transform is $$ \frac{z}{z-1} X(z) $$ where $X(z)$ is the Z transform of signal x.

If we let $$x(n) =  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{2^k}$$ we can calculate it's Z transform but I'm stuck on what to do next, the answer should be $?$ (my professor put wrong answer apparently)

Comment: According to the calculator $S=0.36$, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(\sum_{n%3D0}^{\infty}+\sum_{k%3D0}^{n}+\frac{1}{3^n}++\frac{k}{2^k}))

Comment: The Z transform of $k$ is $\frac{z}{z-1}$ and because of that $\frac{1}{2^k}$ we will replace $z$ with $2z$ and because of that $\frac{1}{3^n}$ we will replace our new $z$ with 3. I get $6/25$ and I don't know where I'm wrong :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a few different results. The $z$-transform $Y(z)$ of $y$ is $$\frac1{1-z}X(z).$$ The $z$-transform $\mathrm{Id}(z)$ of $\mathrm{id}:n \to n$ is $$\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}.$$ So the $z$-transform of the given sequence is $$\frac1{1-\frac{z}3}\frac{\frac{z}6}{(1-\frac{z}6)^2}.$$ Plug in $z=1$ to find the sum $\frac9{25}$.